# fsck: fsck.ext2: not found

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, partitioning, fsck

I have a hosted Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS which won't boot – which is why I thought I could try to check the filesystem with fsck.

Since I can have my provider boot the server in safe-mode and display my original filesystem as a drive located in `/repair` I tried to run `fsck -n /repair` but all this lead to was

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.ext2: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.ext2 for /repair
```

error 2: means system should be rebootet as far as I found out – that didn't help though. I have searched specifically for `fsck.ext2: not found` but I didn't find anything (yet) – where can I get fsck.ext2 from or what are alternatives to it for scanning/repairing the installation?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy e2fsprogs`

Comment: @A.B. As it turned out I had to install the `e2fsprogs` package... But the scan still didn't work... because I now get told that `/repair` is not a file system.

Comment: Can be, but that was not the question. Please ask a new question for the next problem. **;)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to check, if the package `e2fsprogs` is installed, because `fsck.ext2` is part of this package.

Check the installation with:

```
apt-cache policy e2fsprogs
```

and, if necessary, install with:

```
sudo apt-get install e2fsprogs
```